# Android WiFi-Direct Group Formation

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

WiFi-Direct supports several ways in which two devises can establish a P2P group connection (i.e. Standard, Autonomous, Persistent...)
In Android I can't find anything to specify which type of group formation to adopt.

I have noticed that in the WifiP2pManager there are several methods referring to persistent groups stored in the system (such as requestPersistentGroupInfo(...)`)
but cannot access them unless using Reflection.

Is it fair to assume that Android only supports persistent group connection and that Android discourages removing persistent groups?